# Why should methods called from a class constructor be final?

Tags: java, final

I'm a Java novice and I was trying to make sense of the following line from the tutorial at the Oracle website: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

> Methods called from constructors should generally be declared final. If a constructor calls a non-final method, a subclass may redefine that method with surprising or undesirable results.

I tried reading it multiple times trying to make sense of how a method called from a constructor can be redefined by a subclass. Should I assume the method being called by the constructor is one declared within the class of the constructor? And why should a method be declared final if it's called from within a constructor? (As opposed to from within a nested class or within another method?) I wasn't able to wrap my head around that statement. An example would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is valid code (compiles):

```
class Person {
    Person() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    Employee() {
        super();
    }

    void init() {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

And it's highly suspicious. Because `Person.init` might do something critical for the integrity of the class, and there's no guarantees that `Employee.init` will do it too.

Restricting `Person.init` to `private` is not good enough. `Employee.init` remains valid, but it will *shadow* `Person.init`, which will be simply very misleading. It's best to make `Person.init` `final`, which make prohibit creating `Employee.init`.